# Pimple source code: Why to store object id and object itself in different arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, silex, pimple

Looking at the [Pimple source code](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/master/src/Pimple/Container.php#L80-L81) I found that it is storing objects and their ids in two different arrays:

```
class Container implements \ArrayAccess
{
    private $values = array();
    ...
    private $keys = array();
}
```

And then:

```
public function offsetSet($id, $value)
{
    ...
    $this->values[$id] = $value;
    $this->keys[$id] = true;
}
```

And finally:

```
public function offsetGet($id)
{
    if (!isset($this->keys[$id])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Identifier "%s" is not defined.', $id));
    }
}
```

I've also seen something similar in Phalcon source code [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/acl/adapter/memory.zep#L174-L175).

My question is why to store object id key separately, why not just `if (!isset($this->values[$id]))`? Is it faster to search within an array? I did some tests and it seems that search speed is pretty the same.

Comment: Among other things, `$this->values[$id]` can have a value of `NULL`, and this will still identify that it exists, because `$this->keys[$id]` is true

Comment: why not use `array_key_exists` ?

Comment: And what about Phalcon code: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/acl/adapter/memory.zep#L174-L175 ?

Comment: Well `array_key_exists()` has the overhead of a function call, where `isset()` doesn't because it's a control structure, so possibly optimising for testing speed at the expense of setting speed and memory.... I'm offering suggestions, but don't actually know what was in the minds of the developers when they made this decision

Comment: `isset()` is much more efficient than `array_key_exists()`. See this [benchmark](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#107786)

Comment: @doydoy44 I like the solution given in that benchmark `if (isset(...) || array_key_exists(...)){` ill defiantly be implementing this in my projects

Comment: @cmorrissey: I like too. :)

Comment: This was done for performance reasons. Check out [this commit](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/commit/c94869c7396d1617f6191435f0f5828cec40b036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems like when the array entry value may be `null` you have to check key existence with an `array_key_exists()` function. However, this is several times slower than `isset()`, so having keys in the separate array makes possible to use `isset()`. 
But the better way would be `if (isset(...) || array_key_exists(...))`, that has almost the same speed as simple `isset()`, but eliminates the need of separate array for keys tracking (thanks, @doydoy44).